# C# load folder names

Tags: c#

I would like my program to read sub-folders from folder in my solution, but i don't know how to read folder names. I can only find, how to read file names and this is not hard to get to work, but with folders, this doesn't seem to work the same way.

Basically I want to load from "Paevik" (2) sub-folders.

[image]

E: I forgot to mention, that I want that list into my comboBox

Comment: See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(string Path)`-method. It returns a collections with directories. Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string dirPath = @"\\archives\2009\reports";

            List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirPath));

            foreach (var dir in dirs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", dir.Substring(dir.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} directories found.",  dirs.Count);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try  DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories Method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413235.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use "GetDirectories" to retrieve an array containing full names of all subdirectories.

```
string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories("Full path of your parent folder");
```

See sample on [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).