# C# How can I get all of subfolder of the current folder path

Tags: c#

C# How can I get all of subfolder of the current folder path?. For example, I have a **Public** folder that is a parent folder. So in **Public** folder I have **Images** folder, and in **Images** folder I have AA, BB, CC,... folder.

May be any recursive here?

P/S: I want to get the result like the tree view:

```
  Public

  --Images

  ----AA

  ----BB

  ----CC
```

Comment: did you try this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523402/c-sharp-load-folder-names)?

Comment: thank you. But everything I read can not help me. I mean I want to get the subfolder of the subfolder,... of current parent folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that you want to list the subdirectories below a given path that contain only files.

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetSubdirectoriesContainingOnlyFiles(string path)
{
  return from subdirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
  where Directory.GetDirectories(subdirectory).Length == 0
  select subdirectory;
}
```

or You can also use this.

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(<path to dir>);
DirectoryInfo[] subdirs = dInfo.GetDirectories();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Microsoft's [Ix-Main](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix-Main) package:

```
    static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateSubdirs(string path)
    {
        return EnumerableEx.Expand(
                   Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path),
                   subPath => Directory.EnumerateDirectories(subPath));
    }
```

`Expand` will recursively apply a method to a collection, returning each item breadth-first. So, if you pass in "Public" there, it'll give you:

```
Public\Images
Public\Images\AA
Public\Images\BB
Public\Images\CC
```

If you wanted to include the top-level folder, that's plenty easy too:

```
    static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateSubdirs(string path)
    {
        var subDirs = EnumerableEx.Expand(
                   Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path),
                   subPath => Directory.EnumerateDirectories(subPath));

        return EnumerableEx.Return(path).Concat(subDirs);
    }
```

Which would result in:

```
Public
Public\Images
Public\Images\AA
Public\Images\BB
Public\Images\CC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
String[] dirs= System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\");

               foreach(string str in dirs)
                   Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   Dictionary<string, string> dicData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private void processDirectory(string startLocation)
    {
        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(startLocation))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dr = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
            {
                if (!dicData.ContainsKey(dr.Parent.Name))
                    dicData.Add(dr.Parent.Name, dr.Name);
                else
                    dicData[dr.Parent.Name] += "," + dr.Name;
            }
            processDirectory(directory);
        }
    }

A --> B , C
B --> X --> Y -->Z
C --> P --> Q
```